# How to find an integer pair x and y after performing Eucilid algorithm?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

After performing a Euclid algorithm such as finding the greatest common divisor GCD(3745, 1172);

How can I find an X and Y for an equation like 3745x + 1172y = 5 ?

I'm quite confused at how to approach this question so would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: You can find the $x,y$ to make the right side $1$, then multiply them each by $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$3745a+1172b=1 \implies 3745(ra)+1172(rb)=r.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$  \gcd( 3745, 1172 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 3745 }{ 1172 } = 3 +  \frac{ 229 }{ 1172 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1172 }{ 229 } = 5 +  \frac{ 27 }{ 229 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 229 }{ 27 } = 8 +  \frac{ 13 }{ 27 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 27 }{ 13 } = 2 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 13 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 13 }{ 1 } = 13 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 5 & & 8 & & 2 & & 13 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 131 }{ 41 }   & &   \frac{ 278 }{ 87 }   & &   \frac{ 3745 }{ 1172 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  8  \\  
  \frac{ 131 }{ 41 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 278 }{ 87 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  13  \\  
  \frac{ 3745 }{ 1172 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 3745 \cdot 87 - 1172 \cdot 278 = -1 $$

and then.....................